# Building a tower from cubes

Tags: algorithm

You can make stable tower from cubes by not putting bigger to a smaller one and you can't put heavier to a lighter cube.

Write a program which gives you the highest tower from N cubes.

The first row of the input txt contains the number of cubes. (1<=n<=100) In the following N rows there are the cube's length and weight.

Example:

```
Input.txt       Output.txt (from bottom to top)
5               3
10 3            20 5
20 5            10 3
15 6            10 2
15 1
10 2
```

Memory limit: 16 mb Running Time: 0.2 sec

Can you help me?

Comment: Nice problem! I didn't think of sorting by the weights, but once you've done that (and, I suppose, once you've sorted boxes of the same weight by size too), you're looking at solving a "longest non-strictly decreasing subsequence problem" on the heights. Take a look at the [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem and see if you can adjust it to be non-strict and decreasing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to take a look at it.

Comment: So what is the problem? Finding the highest tower or writing this to a file as you said in comment under Sklivvz♦ answer?

Comment: Finding the highest tower, sorry if i am incomprehensible

Comment: @Rawling It's not equivalent to longest non-strictly decreasing subsequence problem. For example imagine if the example input had a cube with length 100 and weight 1. Then that single cube would give you the highest tower.

Comment: @ShashankGupta ... I totally forgot about the height; I was just counting cubes, and using the length purely as for "can it stack or not". That said, maybe you can use the same underlying algortihm, but increment your longest value by side length rather than by 1 each time.

Comment: @ShashankGupta yeah you're right. This is more complicated than I thought..

Comment: looks like SPOJ to me.

Comment: @Rawling: this will be correct if we had to find maximum number of blocks that can be put on each other like stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Algorithm

The algorithm I came up with works by using a list of ordered pairs. The pairs are first ordered by one element, then by the second.

We maintain lists of pairs, where each new pair is either:

- added to the end of the highest list, if it can fit after the last element
- added to the end of a new list, which is a copy of the highest segment found in one of the existing lists, to which it could be appended
- added to a new list if it can't fit anywhere in existing lists.

---

### Proof

1. The first element will go in a new list, which will then be the highest.
2. The ***n***-th element will go to the end of the highest list (or list segment), making it the highest list with that element.
3. The first element after ***n***, element ***k***, that can be appended to the list with ***n*** will be appending to the highest list that contains ***n***, because of 2. If some higher list exists with element ***i*** to which element ***k*** could be appended, then rule 2 is applied to element ***i***. This makes the list with ***k*** the highest list with that element.

By induction, this proves the concept of the algorithm.

---

### Pseudocode

```
foreach ordered pair
    maximumIndex <- 0
    maximumList <- null
    foreach list
        highest, length <- FindLongestPath(list, pair)
        if highest > maximumHeight
            maximumHeight<- highest 
            maximumIndex <- lenght
            maximumList <- list
    if maximumIndex = 0
        lists.add(new list{pair});
    else if maximumIndex < maximumList.Length
        lists.add(new list{maximumList[0..maximumIndex - 1] + pair});
    else
        list.add{pair};
```

The `FindLongestPath` method searches the list for the first place the pair can fit in, and with it it returns the height of this segment. With a straightforward application (`for` from the start until place is found), I estimate the complexity of the algorithm to be O(N^2) on the worst case.

If implemented as a binary search, the complexity would be O(N log N) I guess, but for N <= 100 it doesn't really matter.

---

### Actual Code

Since nobody likes deciphering other peoples pseudo-code, here's the actual working C# code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/3vLn343j

The file, "Input.txt", formatted as in the question, should be in the same directory as the executable (in Visual Studio you can put it in the solution root and in properties set 'Copy to Output' to 'Copy if newer').

Comment: OMG, you're a genious. Thank you very much, but no one will beleive I wrote this so I'll write my own somehow (with the help of yours ofc) :D. Otherwise, I found a little bug in yours, if I add one more cube (100,1) it will give the same: (20,5) (10,3)(10,2) but (100,1) is still larger even though it's one cube.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that by 'length' you had actually meant height. Luckily, it's just a small update in the find method (it adds the heights rather than adding number of cubes. My previous assumption was that you needed to find the tower with most cubes. I'll update it.

Comment: Hey I don't think you should apologize. Thanks again :) I really appreciate your work.

Comment: This is Pancake sort .

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to approach this problem. Here's the *naive* way which is fairly inefficient in pseudocode:

```
// `Input` is a list of `Cube` who have a `Size` and `Weight` property

int largestStack(input_cubes_left, currentCube)
{
   max = 0 // at worst, there are no cubes that fit on top of currentCube
   foreach (cube in input_cubes_left)
   {
      // skip all cubes which don't fit
      if (cube.Size <= current.Size and cube.Weight <= current.Weight)
      {

        // measure the stack with currentCube, this cube, and whatever is left
        size = 1 + largestStack(input_cubes_without_cube, cube)

        // but of course we only count the ones 
        // which are bigger than our best result
        if size>max 
          max = size
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Of course, this is a simplified solution which checks all possible combinations (N factorial!). 
Here are some questions to get you started on optimizing it:

- How can you leverage sorting to avoid checking a lot of invalid combinations?
- How can you leverage Linq to solve this problem functionally?

Comment: continue is unnecessary (modified) and you can relatively easily keep all the stacks instead of the max and only return the longest. probably horribly inefficient to do so though :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, let us assume there is no equal cube (cubes with identical length/weight), build one directed graph following below definition:

1. exactly one node for each cube in graph
2. add edge (A -> B) if cube B can be put on cube A

it's easy to know that this is an DAG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

original problem is equal to finding longest path in DAG. we can use dynamic programming for this problem.

Back to assumption, even consider equal cubes, we can make slight change to cover equal cubes. (each node have attribute - equalCount, the number of equal cubes. and update longest path definition to sum of equalCount along the path, to replace original definition: the number of node along the path)